# How do keyword spellings in domains and titles affect search engine optimization?

Tags: seo, domains, url, title

Just had a quick question about the spellings of words in domain names and how search engines like Google interpret them:

So for example, if I had a site based on up to the minute deals on various products and called it `livedeals.co.uk`, how would the key wording of the word "live" be affected in:

```
www.livedeals.co.uk - Lived Eals or Live Deals
```

Also, is "UK" in `.co.uk` picked up as a keyword too?

Answer (score 4):

In terms of keywords contained domain names:

As covered [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53580/multiple-keywords-sites-for-local-seo/53585#53585) in more detail, domains that contain keywords (aka., "Exact Match Domains") are no longer given more weight by search engines like Google, unless associated with common brand names.

[ccLTDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcTLD) such as [.co.uk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk) are also not considered keywords, though they do help specify regionalism and target audiences.

As for keywords in titles:

You can do Google searches or use their [Keyword Planner](http://adwords.google.com/keywordplanner) tool to see how Google interprets them. Obviously you should use keywords that best match and are relevant to your content, and not ones that search engines users wouldn't use to find your pages.

Comment: Nice to know on the domain names, another SEO kludge instead of content is gone.